# How to disconnect a single client connection in OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn

Would like to forcefully kick a specific user connection.

OS is Ubuntu 16, OVPN Server is OpenVPN 2.3.10

I can see them connected in `/etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log` which lists out current client status. And their persistent connection pool is saved to `/etc/openvpn/ipp.txt`

I can kick **all users** by simply cycling the openvpn daemon `service openvpn restart` **however I want to kick ONE single user**.

I've tried `openvpn --help` and `man openvpn` as well as searched google but not seeing anything.

OS is Ubuntu 16, Server is OpenVPN 2.3.10

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doing this requires some preparation ahead of time.  Specifically you need to enable the Management port (`--management IP port`).  With the management port enabled you can connect to that management port using telnet/netcat and then you can issue commands to disconnect a session (eg `kill client-name`).

See this page for more about the usage of that interface.

- https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html

Comment: Wow thanks so much. Interesting this doc didn't come up while searching various keywords.

Comment: This is a brute force solution and not a great user experience. Because you only kill the connection. The user still believes to be connected to the server. Ideally a disconnect signal should be sent to the user so that the client disconnects properly.